# Use javascript to check if url is a facebook link and a proper url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I wanna check if the url entered by the user is a facebook link. If it's a correct url format and it contains facebook.com on it's url.

My code needs to get the user's facebook profile link. As we all know it's structured as facebook.com/[username].

It must be able to accept examples: www.facebook.com or https://facebook.com or https://www.facebook.com

But the additional is also if it contains the username as stated above which is the correct url for facebook profile link.

What I've tried is this, a basic code to check if the url follows the proper format but still I don't have much knowledge as to where I can check if it contains the facebook word and to check if there's another segment.

```
function validURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}
```

Comment: `return !!pattern.test(str);` should be `return pattern.test(str);`. `RegExp#test()` returns true or false boolean result. Also, there is no need to escape `/` in a RegExp constructor string pattern.